# How to create a Goolge Play Music URI?

Tags: url

For a service I'm building I need to link to google play music. Any idea how to create a URI? Or is there an other way to open google play music?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware Google Play Music only supports sharing URLS rather than embedding to equal that offered by YouTube and other Google services. There is no official API library either but [some people have made there own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707164/is-there-a-google-play-music-api), but be careful as you need to ensure that it doesn't break there terms of use.